# MySQL(XAMPP) won't start

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using XAMPP for php and mySQL.
After a restart the mySQL won't start with this error:

> [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
>
> [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
>
> [ERROR] Aborting

I haven't installed any other db system, I verified and no mysqld process or service is running and i ran a `netstat` and the port 3306 is not used or blocked.
I even tried to change the port into 3307 but no result.

Comment: close skype & teamviewer & iis

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the problem was the fact that i am using a dynamic IP address on my PC and I bound the address in the config file.